# Remover grupo de divs “Clones” em jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho um grupo de divs que pode ser clonada em jquery, preciso que ao clicar em "na imagem da lixeira com a id excluir" remove as divs clonada ao ser clicado...

Segue o código..

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#duplicar").click(function() {
            linha = $("#copia").html();
            $("#base").append("<br />"+linha+"<br />");
            });

        });
    </script>
```

---

```
        <div id="base">
        <div id="copia">
        <form class="questoes">
            <input type="text" name="pergunta" placeholder="Pergunta"><!-- Campo de pergunta-->

            <select><!-- Campo de opções -->
                <option>Resposta Curta</option>
                <option>Parágrafo</option>
                <option>Múltipla Escolha</option>
                <option>Caixas de Seleção</option>
            </select>
        </form><br>

        <form class="resposta"><!-- Campo de resposta-->
            <input type="text" name="resposta">
        </form><br>

        <div class="barra-inferior">

             <div class="area-obrigatorio">
                <label class="obrigatorio" for="obrigatorio"><strong>OBRIGATÓRIA</strong></label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="obrigatorio" id="obrigatorio">
             </div>
             <div class="area-botoes" >
                <img src="img/Defult Text.png" class="dublicar" id="duplicar">
                <img src="img/delete_remove_bin_icon-icons.com_72400.png" class="excluir" id="excluir">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: A tua pergunta diz só _"Remover grupo de divs “Clones” em jquery"_. Podes explicar melhor a pergunta e o que não conseguiste resolver?

Comment: eu crio um clone com:    $("#duplicar").click(function() {
            linha = $("#copia").html();
            $("#base").append("<br />"+linha+"<br />");
            });                                                                                                                 ai quero saber como excluir a copia, sendo que eu vi em um canto que exclui a ultima coisa, eu quero copiar umas 3 divs e excluir depois suas copias

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer assim:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#duplicar").click(function() {
        // coloca um id e uma classe para cada div copiada 
        var id = +(new Date());
        $clone = $("#copia").clone();
        $clone.attr('id', 'copia-'+id).addClass('div-copia');
        $("#base").append("<br />"+$clone+"<br />");
    });

    // no click do excluir você procura pelo elemento pai e o remove
    $(document).on('click', '.excluir', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this),
            $div = $this.parent('.div-copia');
        $div.remove();
      });
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: fernando eu acho que serviu mas eu devo adimitir que sou bastante iniciante em jquery e meio que fiquei perdido em onde deveria colocar id , classe e o elemento pai seria no caso o #copia ou #base ou ate mesmo a id da primeira copia